How do I allow decimals to be plotted without being 'flagged' by my format check?
Im trying to make a python script that will allow me to insert a string of coordinates and have them plotted on a graph/plane, I have it set so if you use an incorrect format eg: (x,y), (x,y ,(x,y) that it will say incorrect format becaue of the missing parenthisis however, whenever I try to get it to allow decimal points it either keeps flagging everything or just doesnt connect them via lines. I have it so it will connect the points via lines in the order they were listed if a comma is used to seperate the different coordinates eg: (x,y), (x,y) however if a period is used in between points it won't connect a line between those specific points eg: (x,y). (x,y) this allows me to make things that look like a completed connect the dots, however that breaks a lot of the time when trying to allow decimal points as it gets confused between whats a decimal point and whats a line seperator. I know that decimals need to be declaired as a 'float' unlike whole numbers, and my code doesnt do that and ive yet to figure out how to do so. Does anyone know how I can get my code to allow decimals whilst not breaking the other stuff? The code I have so far has working lines, and line seperation via the periods, however it doesnt accept decimal numbers. Im also using Google Colab if that helps:
    # Import necessary libraries
import plotly.graph_objects as go  # Library for creating interactive plots
import ipywidgets as widgets        # Library for creating interactive widgets in Jupyter notebooks
from IPython.display import display, clear_output  # Function to clear previous output in Jupyter notebooks

# Function to plot points on a Cartesian plane
def plot_points(points):
    try:
        # Split the input string based on periods and commas
        segments = points.split('.')
        all_points = []
        # Iterate over each segment and convert it to a list of tuples
        for segment in segments:
            segment_points = eval('[' + segment + ']')  # Convert segment to list of tuples
            all_points.extend(segment_points)          # Extend the list of all points with segment points

        # Extract x and y coordinates from all points
        x_values = [point[0] for point in all_points]  # Extract x coordinates
        y_values = [point[1] for point in all_points]  # Extract y coordinates

        # Create a new plotly figure
        fig = go.Figure()

        # Add a scatter trace for all points
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x_values, y=y_values, mode='markers', name='Points'))

        # Add traces for the lines connecting the points in each segment
        start_idx = 0
        for segment in segments:
            segment_points = eval('[' + segment + ']')    # Convert segment to list of tuples
            num_points = len(segment_points)
            if num_points > 1:  # If segment has more than one point, add line connecting them
                end_idx = start_idx + num_points
                segment_x_values = x_values[start_idx:end_idx]
                segment_y_values = y_values[start_idx:end_idx]
                fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=segment_x_values, y=segment_y_values, mode='lines+markers',
                                         line=dict(color='blue', width=2), name=''))
                start_idx = end_idx  # Update start index for the next segment

        # Update layout of the plot
        fig.update_layout(title='Points on Cartesian Plane',
                          xaxis_title='X-Axis', yaxis_title='Y-Axis',  # Set axis titles
                          xaxis=dict(range=[-99, 99], autorange=False),  # Set x-axis range and disable autorange
                          yaxis=dict(range=[-99, 99], autorange=False, showticklabels=False),  # Set y-axis range and disable tick labels
                          showlegend=False,  # Hide legend
                          width=600, height=575)  # Set width and height to make it square

        fig.show()  # Show the plot
    except SyntaxError:
        # Display error message if there's a syntax error in the input format
        error_message.value = "Incorrect format. Please enter points in the format (x1, y1).(x2, y2), ..."
        display(error_message)
        display(points_input)
        display(plot_button)

# User input box for points
points_input = widgets.Text(description="Points:")

# Error message display
error_message = widgets.HTML(value="", layout=widgets.Layout(color='red'))

# Plot button
plot_button = widgets.Button(description="Plot")

def on_plot_button_clicked(b):
    clear_output()  # Clear previous output
    error_message.value = ""  # Clear previous error message
    plot_points(points_input.value)

plot_button.on_click(on_plot_button_clicked)

# Display the input box and plot button initially
display(points_input)
display(plot_button)


I don't understand why you want to use dot for this.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

if you split data at dot then you may have to copy last value from first part to next part as first element to have connection.

Alright il try that.

can you give an example of what you mean?

I wrote last comment but I don't know if I understand what you want to do with this dot. So forget last comment.

maybe you should use ; or | to separate data - and then you don't have problem with decimals

I used dot because it worked, if you think it isnt effecient or there is a better way to do it im more then willing to try!

Il try that and see if it works.

I cant figure out how to get it to work.

I was thinking about strings like (x,y);(x,y) and using .split(';'). But frankly, if you use eval() then you could use commas and put full string in eval( "[" + "(x,y),(x,y)" + "]" ) to get list - without using split()
